# Recoding variables in R using the %in% operator to avoid NAs

Tags: r

I am scoring a psychometric instrument at work and want to recode a few variables. Basically, each question has five possible responses, worth 0 to 4 respectively. That is how they were coded into our database, so I don't need to do anything except sum those. However, there are three questions that have reversed scores (so, when someone answers 0, we score that as 4). Thus, I am "reversing" those ones.

The data frame basically looks like this:

```
studyid  timepoint      date      inst_q01  inst_q02  ...  inst_q20
   1         2       1995-03-13       0         2     ...      4
   2         2       1995-06-15       1         3     ...      4
```

Here's what I've done so far.

```
# Survey Processing
# Find missing values (-9) and confusions (-1), and sum them
project_f03$inst_nmiss <- rowSums(project_f03[,4:23]==-9)
project_f03$inst_nconfuse <- rowSums(project_f03[,4:23]==-1)
project_f03$inst_nmisstot <- project_f03$inst_nmiss + project_f03$inst_nconfuse

# Recode any missing values into NAs
for(x in 4:23) {project_f03[project_f03[,x]==-9 | project_f03[,x]==-1,x] <- NA}
rm(x)
```

Now, everything so far is pretty fine, I am about to recode the three reversed ones. Now, my initial thought was to do a simple loop through the three variables, and do a series of assignment statements something like below:

```
# Questions 3, 11, and 16 are reversed
for(x in c(3,11,16)+3) {

    project_f03[project_f03[,x]==4,x] <- 5
    project_f03[project_f03[,x]==3,x] <- 6
    project_f03[project_f03[,x]==2,x] <- 7
    project_f03[project_f03[,x]==1,x] <- 8
    project_f03[project_f03[,x]==0,x] <- 9
    project_f03[,x] <- project_f03[,x]-5
}
rm(x)
```

So, the five assignment statements just reassign new values, and the loop just takes it through all three of the variables in question. Since I was reversing the scale, I thought it was easiest to offset everything by 5 and then just subtract five after all recodes were done. The main issue, though, is that there are NAs and those NAs result in errors in the loop (naturally, `NA==4` returns an `NA` in R). Duh - forgot a basic rule!

I've come up with three alternatives, but I'm not sure which is the best.

- First, I could obviously just move the NA-creating code after the loop, and it should work fine. Pros: easiest to implement. Cons: Only works if I am receiving data with no innate (versus created) NAs.
- Second, I could change the logic statement to be something like:
  `project_f03[!is.na(project_f03[,x]) && project_f03[,x]==4,x]` which should eliminate the logic conflict. Pros: not too hard, I know it works. Cons: A lot of extra code, seems like a kludge.
- Finally, I could change the logic from
  `project_f03[project_f03[,x]==4,x] <- 5` to
  `project_f03[project_f03[,x] %in% 4,x] <- 5`. This seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice, and wanted to get thoughts. Pros: quick fix for this issue and seems to work; preserves general syntatic flow of "blah blah LOGIC blah <- bleh". Cons: Might create black hole? Not sure what the potential implications of using `%in%` like this might be.

**EDITED TO MAKE CLEAR**

This question has one primary component: Is it safe to utilize `%in%` as described in the third point above when doing logical operations, or are there reasons not to do so?

The second component is: What are recommended ways of reversing the values, like some have described in answers and comments?

Comment: I haven't read your post completely but I saw reverse score.  Here's how I would do it (if it's wrong ignore; if right tell me and I'll post as an answer).  For one column use `(max(x) + 1) - x`, so an example would be: `x <- sample(0:4, 20, T); (max(x) + 1) - x`.  For multiple columns turn it into a function and use inside of an `apply` function.

Comment: It's a useful idea, and one that I'll make use of (though I think that it's not as intuitive looking as the other answer down there), but it doesn't really answer the inquiry. Still helpful, though! Put it as an answer and I'll definitely upvote it.

Comment: I think you'll get a better response if you eliminate some of the extra stuff in your post a bit.  Perhaps show a sample data frame (8 rows maybe) and a sample out put of what you want to occur.  Otherwise we're more guessing at what you have and what you want.

Comment: IMHO, better than everything you suggested is to do: `project_f03[,x] <- rev(0:4)[match(project_f03[,x], 0:4)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward answer is that there is no black hole to using `%in%`. But in instances where I want to just discard the `NA` values, I'd use `which`: `project_f03[which(project_f03[,x]==4),x] <- 5`

`%in%` could shorten that earlier bit of code you had:

```
for(x in 4:23) {project_f03[project_f03[,x]==-9 | project_f03[,x]==-1,x] <- NA}
#could be
for(x in 4:23) {project_f03[project_f03[,x] %in% c(-9,-1), x] <- NA}
```

Like @flodel suggested, you can replace that whole block of code in your for-loop with `project_f03[,x] <- rev(0:4)[match(project_f03[,x], 0:4, nomatch=10)]`. It should preserve `NA`. And there are probably more opportunities to simplify code.

Comment: I'm seeing this instead: `Warning message:
In max(i) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: I don't get the error when I try the assign: `a <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10); a[which(a$a==6),2] <- 5`

Comment: Going back and looking at the code I ran, I had an unrelated error in it. I will shortly delete my comments since they are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer your question, but should fix your problem:

```
cols <- c(3,11,16)+3
project_f03[, cols] <- abs(project_f03[, cols]-4)
## or a lot of easier (as @TylerRinker suggested):
project_f03[, cols] <- max(project_f03[, cols]) - project_f03[, cols]
```

Comment: +1 for being useful, but it doesn't really answer the question per se. But that's still nice, thanks!